# Java Input Numbers

Tags: java, swing, input, numbers

I made ​​a method to input numbers. But I want that input is numeric but a dot (.) Can still be entered. please my friend help me. Thanks

```
private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    FilterHanyaAngka(evt);
}

public void FilterHanyaAngka(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    if (!((Character.isDigit(c) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)))) {
            evt.consume();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `KeyListener` to filter content to the a text component, you have no idea of knowing in what order the `KeyListener`s will be notified and the key stroke may already have being sent to the field before you.

Instead you should use a `DocumentFilter`

Take a look at [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html), in particular [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [here for examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

In fact, I believe there is actually a numeric filter example listed there...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ASCII` instead of the Character or KeyEvent class.
Look at this:

```
public class ASCIITest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char c = '3';

    if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || c == '.') {
        //some code..
    }
}
```

}

For more information read about the [ASCII chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Answer (score 0):

yes I've found the solution in my opinion

```
public void filterDesimal(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    char ch = evt.getKeyChar();
    if (!((ch == '.') ||
            (ch ==  '0') ||
            (ch ==  '1') ||
            (ch ==  '2') ||
            (ch ==  '3') ||
            (ch ==  '4') ||
            (ch ==  '5')||
            (ch ==  '6') ||
            (ch ==  '7') ||
            (ch ==  '8') ||
            (ch ==  '9') ||
            (ch ==  ',') ||
            (ch ==  KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||
            (ch ==  KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)
            )){
        evt.consume();
    }
}
```